# QGIS labels can't be moved

Tags: qgis, labeling

QGIS 3.30.2 on Windows 10 Pro Suddenly mid-project, labels for one particular line layer which could be moved previously are no longer moveable. The labels for another point layer in the same project are still moveable. The error message I get is:

```
Move Label: The label anchor text point column auxiliary_storage_labeling_lineanchortextpoint does not exist in the layer.
```

I have tried adding X, Y and Rotation attributes to the layer table, and I've also tried storing the data in the project, but neither remove the error.

Comment: Thank you, Babel, for your detailed answer.  I'll work my way through it.

Comment: First I deleted the Auxiliary Layer as suggested.  Then I selected a label to move.  It prompted and I selected field PFI for the key.  It has unique values.  But then I clicked on the label to move it and got the same error message as before "Move Label: The label anchor text point column “auxiliary_storage_labeling_lineanchortextpoint” does not exist in the layer".  This seems to suggest that QGIS still expects Auxiliary Storage to exist even though I deleted it.  so then I checked again and saw that Auxilary Stroage had been re-created with two fields PositionX and PositionY.

Comment: I've now seem to have got things working OK.  I deleted the layer and re-loaded it from the existing Shape file, then followed Babel's giudelines.  I checked and saw that no Auxiliary Layer had been "secretly" created.  I chose a unique field as the key and success!  Thanks to Babel for leading me in the correct direction.

Comment: Forgot to say that Auxiliary Layer was created after I assigned the key, and it includes a field called labeling_lineanchortextpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer: primary key lost

You lost the primary key (an attribute field with unique values) and QGIS can't make the join between the label movement and the feature. Recreate the deleted or renamed field or delete the automatically created Auxiliary Layer to start from scratch.

***Recommandation**: always select a field as primary key based on variable [`@id` (`$id` before QGIS 3.28)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-record-and-attributes-id). Like this, it's easy to re-create the values in case you accidentally delete the field as `@id`/`$id` values for each feature will never change. Very handy as QGIS handles this automatically.*

### Details: recreate primary key

When you move the first label, a dialog window pops up asking you to `Select the primay key to use for joining with internal data storage`. You must select an attribute field containing unique values:

[image]

If you later, by accident, delete the field you selected, QGIS can't associate the values of the auxiliary fields QGIS creates automatically to store the x-/y-shift of the labels. So it's not clear any more which value corresponds to which feature and thus, you can't move labels any more.

The solution is to recreate the field you initially defined in the dialog above. Make sure you choose the same field type and to have unique values. To see which fieldname you used to define the primary key, go to <kbd>Layer Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Auxiliary Storage</kbd> tab. There you see the `Key` value, here: `id`. You could also go to Auxiliary Layer dropdown menu (at the bottom, see next screenshot) and select `delete` (**all prior label movements will be deleted!**).

Like this, you will be prompted to define a new primary key field.

[image]

Comment: I've checked the unique key field PFID and all appears intact there.  I note that the 8  auxiliary storage fields created by checking the 'Store data in project' boxes on the Placement and Rendering screens do NOT include labeling_lineanchortextpoint.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.  I tried again to move a label and it worked.  If the problem appears again with another layer, I'll re-comment.  Thanks to Babel for advice.

Comment: If your comment is not relevant any more, you have the possibility to delete it.

Comment: This seems to have been reported as an issue here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47542

I'm running 3.22 and deleting and recreating the auxiliary storage isn't working.
Tried copying the layer as well.

It seems like the whole layer is corrupted now.
see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427529/cant-create-auxiliary-storage-layer-in-qgis-in-order-to-move-labels

Answer (score 0):

An alternative workaround is to save everything you can for the layer and recreate it if deleting and recreating auxiliary storage doesn't work (github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47542 ?), saving as a QGIS QML Style file doesn't seem to save the problem but will save everything else.
[image: Save Layer Style]